# How to use function similar to vlookup pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I use function similar to vlookup in pandas.

df 1:

```
       AS     G    DA     VV     VV
0  potato    this  is   spart  today
1  potato  surely  not    the    day
2     you  retire  is      it    day
```

df 2:

```
        V     V     VA      ZD     VE
0       a  does  potato    even   work
1       I    am  potato    even  today
2       O   how  potato  mighty   have
3  fallen     O  potato       K      R
```

Data-frame I am desiring:

```
        V     V     VA      ZD     VE
0       a  does  potato    even   work
1       I    am  potato       even  today
2       O   how  NaN      mighty   have
3  fallen     O  NaN       K      R
```

I've tried-

```
df1.insert(2, 'VA', df1['AS'].map(df2.set_index('AS')['VA']))
#KeyError#####
```

Comment: `Keyerror` obviously means there are no columns for select. So what is `print (df1.columns.tolist())` and `print (df2.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: @jezrael  df2.VA=np.where(df2.VA.isin(df1.AS),df2.VA,np.nan).  This gives: potato, potato, potato, potato.  I want one potato.  It is reading off same dataframe.

Comment: Then need `df2['VA'] = df2['VA'].mask(df2['VA'].duplicated())` for convert duplicates to NaNs.

Comment: @jezrael That removes all duplicates but there are 2 potatoes in other data-frame.  This just reads same data-frame and removes dups.

Comment: @jezrael 3 different methods and all give me 4 potatoes :\

Comment: Yes, there is problem with duplicates, give me a sec for solution.

Comment: @jezrael Why is it reading the own data-frame rather than getting 2 from other data-frame?  Ha.

Comment: I am a bit confused with your desired output. Because in `df1` are not `VA` column. Also if duplicates columns names it is bad too, because it should failed. Can you check it? What is desired output from your input? There are some column(s) from `df1` mapped to `df2` ? Or only `As` ?

Comment: @jezrael I updated question while ago thats exact data I am looking at

Comment: @jezrael Is df2.VA=np.where(df2.VA.isin(df1.AS),df2.VA,np.nan) not correct?

Comment: It depends what you need. But code seems OK

Comment: @jezrael So it work for you?  :|

Comment: @jezrael Pandas bug hell LOL.  I'

Comment: No, try find what id do - check if values of `df1.AS` are in `df2.VA`. And because there are all potatoes it return all `True`s. So it working nice. But it is not what you need.

Comment: @jezrael I'm having second thoughts about using Pandas if it does this for no reason.  Is it bug or am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check comemnt above.

Comment: @jezrael Csv's screw up formatting a lot.  That worked.